# Best way to get the model object that has a DateTime field closest in DateTime to current DateTime

Tags: python, django

I want to make an efficient ORM query that returns the model object in which the objects datetime is the closest to the current datetime.

So if the current datetime is `22/08/2022 15:00` and I have objects with datetimes of `object1.datetime == 22/08/2022 15:30` and `object2.datetime == 22/08/2022 15:45` I want to be able to query the DB for the object with the closest datetime which would be the `object1` object.

*So basically I want to find the object that is closest, in the future, to the current datetime.*

The only solutions I've been able to think of are inefficient and involve looping and comparing multiple objects by adding them to lists etc.

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
objs = Model.objects.all()
for obj in objs:
    if obj.dateTime //etc...
```

Obviously this isn't a good solution because it's going to loop through my whole model database. How can I make this query in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
dt = original_object.dateTime

# get all objects with date later or equal to current
query = Model.objects.filter(dateTime__gte=dt)

# order them by `dateTime`
query = query.order_by("dateTime")

# exclude original object
query = query.exclude(id=original_object.id)

# pick first, since it should be the closest to your original object
closest_object = query.first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using objects.filter range datetimes and order the queryset

```
model.objects.filter(date__gte=d2,date__lte=d1).order_by('date')[0]
```